# Potential difference?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Potential difference is the difference in electrical potential energy per unit charge between two points in an electrical circuit.

In an electrical circuit, a battery causes a potential difference - electrons flow from an area of higher potential (the negative terminal) to an area of lower potential (the negative terminal) and then are raised up to the higher potential area again by the battery.

If this is the case, and electrons are essentially 'falling' through the potential difference as they go around the circuit, they are presumably losing electric potential energy and gaining kinetic energy all of the time (until they reach the positive terminal, at which point the cycle starts again).

This means that there should be a potential difference between any two points in a circuit, even if there is no component between the points, as a coulomb of charge has slightly lower electrical potential energy slightly further on in the circuit than slightly earlier on, which is of course a potential difference.

Also, surely energy could not be transferred to components directly adjacent to the negative terminal, as the electrons would not have 'fallen' for long enough to transfer enough of their stored energy into kinetic energy and then give this energy to the components.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated - I don't have advanced physics knowledge (as you can probably tell) so please try to keep it simple.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. There is no question here.

Answer (score 0):

> they are presumably losing electric potential energy and gaining kinetic energy all of the time

You're forgetting that the electrons are also losing kinetic energy due to interacting with the material around them. They "scatter" off the nuclei of the material, transferring their kinetic energy to the nuclei. Since the nuclei are not mobile, this produces vibrational waves in the material rather than sending the nuclei off in motion.

See the wiki article [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) for more details.

> This means that there should be a potential difference between any two points in a circuit, even if there is no component between the points,

This is true, but often the potential difference between the two ends of a wire is small enough to ignore for all practical purposes. For example, it might be a few microvolts in a 5 V circuit.

> Also, surely energy could not be transferred to components directly adjacent to the negative terminal, as the electrons would not have 'fallen' for long enough to transfer enough of their stored energy into kinetic energy and then give this energy to the components.

The electric fields in the circuit continue to exert force on the electrons, regardless of how far they have "fallen" before reaching any particular point.

And the constant interaction with the material means the electrons never build up substantial kinetic energy at any point in the wires of a circuit in any case. (Vacuum tubes and certain analogous semiconductor devices being the exception where *ballistic transport* is significant)